# How to notify if a Worker is force exit or crash to Dealer

Tags: zeromq

I'm using the pattern:

```
PUSHER (Client) -> ROUTER -> DEALER -> PULL (Worker)
```

But, sometimes, the Worker is crashed and the onExit function can not be invoked.

I this case, what should I do?
And how to notify if a Worker is force exit or crash to Dealer?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Once the worker crashes there is nothing it can do. The dealer needs verify which workers are alive.

Comment: @jschiavon: I use zmq version 2.x, so dealer does not know a worker is  dead.

Comment: @vietean: You need the workers to signal when they finish their task. A task needs to be pushed again if it does not finish because the worker crashed. Pushers follow the 'fire and forget' pattern. You might need to use a different one to ensure tasks get done. Check the guide